# RCP application Hang

Tags: eclipse-rcp, jface, freeze

In my Eclipse RCP project, when I retrieve and load large data say around (100000) in Tableviewer, the RCP application hangs.

Can anybody tell me why the RCP application hangs and what is the solution for this problem?

Comment: Suggest to use [Nebula Pagination](http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/pagination/pagination.php) or use lazy loading of your data.

Comment: I am use Tableviewer with VIRTUAL flag.

Comment: Update the code you tried with

Comment: Are you retrieving your data in thread? Long time to retrieve data in sequential function may cause problem.

Comment: No,i am not using any thread. but retrieve data through query take time

Answer (score 3):

It is really important how do you load your data. If you do it in UI thread, then it will block your application from being responsive, until everything is loaded. Consider loading data in separate Thread (use [Jobs](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJobs/article.html) for this purpose).

Also, I would like to encourage you to take a look at the Nebula [NatTable](http://www.eclipse.org/nattable/) project. It is just perfect for working with huge amounts of data.

Answer (score 0):

Refer these examples its difficult to guess why your program hangs.

[SWT snippets](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/), Go to **"Table, TableItem, TableColumn"** section

Answer (score 0):

this is old, but i will add my answer anyway :D

I believe this is a memory allocation problem, try to extend the allocated memory for the RCP application in run time by adding the argument : "-XX:PermSize=1024M" in run configuration arguments area.

Also for extracted RCP app you can change the allocated memory by adjusting the same argument value in the "configuration settings" file extracted in the same folder of your app.